# What happened to previous Gnomes queen in Gravity Falls?

Tags: gravity-falls

In the first Gravity Falls episode named "Tourist Trapped", gnomes are looking for a new queen. But what happened to the previous one?

Comment: the previous queen was eaten by a badger or some other carniverous woodland creature